# Web App - iphone app icon

Tags: asp.net, iphone, web-applications, visual-studio-2013, iphone-web-app

well I've searched upon the web for an answer, yet to find a solution.

I'm trying to add an iPhone web app icon (the one when you save the webpage to your home-screen) through the following code:

```
<link href="http://localhost:5001/Images/cc.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<link href="http://localhost:5001/Images/cc-76x76.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" />
<link href="http://localhost:5001/Images/cc-120x120.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" />
<link href="http://localhost:5001/Images/cc-152x152.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" />
```

**P.S** - I'm programming using Visual Studios 2013 and running the app through localhost

After some research I came to a conclusion that my problem might be in how I link the image's place - people say you need to place it in the root document folder but I couldn't figure out how to do so

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add a simple bit of code to the HEAD of your site so the devices can find your images ,it is recommended to create the icon for the respective sizes and add them to your site's root folder)
Code is as follows (According to ios 7)-

`<link href="http://www.yoursite.com/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<link href="http://www.yoursite.com/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" />
<link href="http://www.yoursite.com/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" />
<link href="http://www.yoursite.com/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" />`